# How to limit number of objects returned from ListObjects

Tags: c++, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to set a `MaxResults()` in order to return a max number of objects from `ListObjects`. However, `MaxResults()` doesn't seem to limit the number of objects returned. If I set `MaxResults(5)` and there are 10 objects in the bucket, there will be 2 requests sent and all objects will be returned. If I changed to `MaxResults(10)`, 1 request is sent to return all objects.

Is it possible to return a **bool** if the result is **truncated** and to return a **next marker** to make another `ListObjects()` call if required, so `ListObjects()` only returns the `MaxResults()` specified?

The following code is what I am using to list objects:

```
google::cloud::StatusOr<gcs::ListObjectsReader> response = m_client->ListObjects(m_bucket, gcs::MaxResults(count));
if (!response) {
  auto error = response.status();
  std::cout << error << std::endl;
}

list_objects_response out;
auto object_metadata = response->begin();

for (object_metadata ; object_metadata != response->end() ; ++object_metadata) {
  out.keys.push_back(object_metadata->value().name());
}
```

`list_objects_response` is a struct containing **vector of keys**, **bool truncated** and **string next token**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m_client->ListObjects()` returns an iterator (via the `ListObjectsReader` class) which iterates through all objects in the bucket, or just the objects with a specified prefix.  The results are paged, and the iterator internally handles moving from page to page as needed.  `MaxResults` simply limits the page size, not the result size.  The iterator continued until all pages have been consumed.

If you want to limit the iteration to only `count` number of objects, then simply keep track of how many objects you have read from the iterator and stop when you have read `count` objects, eg:

```
google::cloud::StatusOr<gcs::ListObjectsReader> response = m_client->ListObjects(m_bucket);
if (!response) {
  auto error = response.status();
  std::cout << error << std::endl;
}

list_objects_response out;
int numRecvd = 0;

for (auto object_metadata = response->begin(); object_metadata != response->end() && numRecvd < count; ++object_metadata, ++numRecvd) {
  out.keys.push_back(object_metadata->value().name());
}
```

Of course, that does mean the iterator might retrieve more objects internally than you actually need to read, but you can use `MaxResults` to limit the page size to reduce the number of extra objects that are received.

However, once you are done using the `ListObjectsReader`, that's it. You can't pick up later where you left off.  You can't pass in a `token` to `ListObjects()`, it starts over from the beginning every time you call it.  So, you will have to either:

- preserve the `ListObjectsReader` for later use.
- drop down to the REST level and handle the paging yourself manually, per Google's [Paginate results](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/paginate-results) documentation in the `REST APIs` section, so that you have access to the token you are interested in.

Comment: All I would add is: you can use `StartOffset` to resume the iteration from the last object you saw:

https://cloud.google.com/cpp/docs/reference/storage/latest/structgoogle_1_1cloud_1_1storage_1_1StartOffset

Comment: @coryan you could, but note that `StartOffset` is inclusive, so you would receive the last object again and have to ignore it. Also, multiple objects in a bucket can have the same name (they are differentiated by their generation numbers), so if the last object has the same name as other objects then you wouldn't know which object you actually last received and which object you would be starting with, unless you compare their metadatas.